# Unused variables in partial views need to be explicitly set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing this in a partial to build a breadcrumb indication:

```
  .header-section
    %ul.breadcrumb.breadcrumb-top
      %li
        %i.fa.fa-home
      -if !level1.nil?
        %li
          =level1
      -if !level2.nil?
        %li
          =level2
```

level2 won't always be used.  However I'm when I'm calling the partial like this:

```
= render :partial => 'layouts/info_header', :locals => {:title => 'Your clients', :level1 => link_to('Clients', clients_path) }
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `level2'
```

I need to call it like this to avoid it:

```
= render :partial => 'layouts/info_header', :locals => {:title => 'Your clients', :level1 => link_to('Clients', clients_path), :level2 => nil }
```

Why is this?  I don't want to explicitly assign nil to level2 if it isn't being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `nil?` on undefined variables. Try `defined?`:

```
- if defined?(level2) && !level2.nil?
    %li
        = level2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to pass an array to locals and iterate over that array to DRY things up a bit

```
= render partial: 'layouts/info_header', locals: { title: 'Your clients', levels: [link_to('Clients', clients_path), link_to('Something else', something_else_path)] }
```

In the partial you can do something like:

```
- if levels.any?
  - levels.each do |level|
    %li= level
```

You could take it level deeper, define a helper method to generate the levels array which would further cleanup the view.